# If $P$ and $Q$ are polynomials and $P(a)$ divides $Q(a)$ for every $a\in\mathbb Z$, does it mean that $P$ divides $Q$?

Tags: polynomials, modular-arithmetic

> Let $P$ and $Q$ be polynomials with integer coefficients such that $P(a)$ divides $Q(a)$ in $\mathbb Z$ for every integer $a$. Does it mean that $P$ divides $Q$ in ${\mathbb Z}[X]$?

$P(a)$ divides $Q(a)$ means that there exists an integer $k(a)$ such that $Q(a)=k(a)P(a)$, so $Q=kP$. This means that $P$ divides $Q$ if $k$ is polynomial with integer coefficients. But I can't find a proof or a counter-example. Any idea?

For the context, I was looking at a proof of the fact that $X^2-X+1$ divides $X^{2n+1}+(X=1)^{n+2}$ for every $n\ge 1$ (in a video of Michael Penn I think but I am not sure). The method used was to consider congruences modulo $P(X)=X^2-X+1$. This is fine and clever method, but my students don't know arithmetic in ${\mathbb Z}[X]$, so I tried to circumvent the problem by looking at congruence in $\mathbb Z$ modulo $P(a)$ for every $a\in\mathbb Z$. But I hit the problem stated above to conclude the reasoning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does it mean that $P$ divides $Q$ in ${\mathbb Z}[X]$

No, take for example $\,P(X)=2, \,Q(X)=X^2+X\,$.

> $X^2-X+1$ divides $X^{2n+1}+(X-1)^{n+2}$

Hint: if $\,x^2-x+1=0\,$ then $\,x-1=x^2\,$, so $\,x^{2n+1}+(x-1)^{n+2}=x^{2n+1}+x^{2n+4}=\dots$